# Implementing SVD using eig

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I am trying to implement SVD using `np.linalg.eig` method for an image compression assignment. We are not allowed to use the `np.linalg.svd` method directly.

Here is my svd method:

```
def svd(A):
    evals, U = LA.eig(A @ A.T)
    evals2, V = LA.eig(A.T @ A)
    idx = evals.argsort()[::-1]
    evals = evals[idx]
    U = U[:, idx]
    idx = evals2.argsort()[::-1]
    V = V[ :, idx]
    sigma = np.array(list(map(math.sqrt, evals)))
    return U, sigma, V.T
```

But when I try to reconstruct the image using U and V returned by the above svd, the error rate is so much that the image is completely blurry even after using all the singular vectors. Whereas when I try the same reconstruction procedure with the U & V matrices returned by `np.linalg.svd`, I am able to clearly reconstruct the image.

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with my svd method.

Comment: The SVD and eigenvalue decomposition are not related this this way for general matrices. Only _normal_ and _positive semi-definite_ matrices have this relationship, and apparently your image is not such a matrix. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition) for more information.

Comment: Implementation is by the definition of SVD. It holds for ANY m*n real matrix. What they have mentioned https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition[here] is a special case of EVD.

Answer (score 1):

Both SVD and eigenvectors are not fully unique. In SVD you can sign flip any vector in U as long as you do the same to the corresponding vector in V. The eigenvectors you get are not coupled in that way, therefore there is a good chance of sign mismatch. You can check and correct for that by using the fact that U.T@A@V.T is sigma, so check the signs of the diagonal elements of U.T@A@V.T and for each negative one flip the corresponding vector in either U or V (but not in both).

Additional suggestions:

Since you only need the diagonal elements it is wasteful to compute the full product U.T@A@V.T; the simplest way to compute only diagonal elements would be `np.einsum('ij,ik,jk->j',U,A,V)`.

Use `eigh` instead of `eig` because you know A@A.T and A.T@A are symmetric.

You can save one eigen decomposition because sigma@V = U.T@A and sigma being diagonal is easy to invert. This also has the advantage that the above sign problem can't happen.